# Regex - Invalid regular expression: '(?:[v=)', no argument for repetition operator:?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query that I'm using in Snowflake:

```
Select *,
case  WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[v=)') is not null THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]v=([0-9]+)')
else null
end
from my_table;
```

but when I try to run it, it tells me:

> Invalid regular expression: '(?:[v=)', no argument for repetition
> operator: ?

but I've tested this out on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/WyQD8W/1) and it looks like its working, I want to check for `[v=`

Edit: More insight into what I'm trying to find w. the regex, I have rows that look like this `test [v=123]`, `words [v=444]`, `more [v=532]` and I need to be able to look through each column and find if it has `[v=` and extract the numbers only

Comment: . . There are multiple implementations of regular expressions which differ in subtle (and not-so-subtle) ways.  You should not need a `case` expressions for this, because `regexp_substr()` returns `NULL`, which is why my answer on your previous question did not have a `case` expression.

Comment: Most probably just remo `?:`. Use `'\\[v='` or `'[[]v='` instead of `'(?:\[v=)'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for responding to both! the reason I have to keep the case when is because its from a much larger query 300+ lines long that already has a case when statement that I'm just  trying to add a few lines to so I'm trying to keep the case when, and I'm just using the 'select *' to test out but that's not the entire query

Comment: @KristiLuna . . . perhaps you can just use `like`:  `where name like '%[v=%'`.

Comment: Can you give us a set of example inputs and desired outputs? Then we can solve this with a different set of regex operators (supported with Snowflake)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa the rows I'm trying to find look like this: ' test [v=111] ' or ' anothertest [v=222] and I'm trying to extract 222 and 111 from them. I will update my main question as well with my input/output

Comment: Did you try `SELECT *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, '[[]v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'e') from my_table;` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you this answer works! I have to read up on what the last few characters you mentioned---  1, 1, 'e'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, '[[]v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'e') from my_table;
```

Here,

- `[[]v=([0-9]+)` matches `[v=` and then captures one or more digits into Group 1
- `1, 1, 'e'` means that we start matching from the first char, one occurrence, and the `e` makes the engine fetch the Group 1 value (it is default, if you needed Group 2 (if you had it in the pattern) value, you woul add another param, and use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, '[[](v|V)=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'e', 2)`).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, 'v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'e') val from values ('foo'), ('test [v=111] ') , (' anothertest [v=222]') t(Name) ;

VAL
null
111
222
```